# VBA to Copy-Paste, run Macro and print file

Tags: vba, excel

So, I'm a noob on VBA programming. I am trying to make a VBA code to: Open two spreadsheets, copy the whole content from one to another, run a macro on sheet 2, then print sheet 2 and close both. I found bits and pieces of each one of these stuff but didn't managed to put it all together in cohesive code. Here's what I got:

```
Option Explicit
ExcelMacroExample
Sub ExcelMacroExample()
Dim xlApp
Dim xlBook
Sheets("Lista Definitiva.xlsm").Range("A1:AD135").Value = Sheets ("A.xls").Range("A1:AD135").Value
set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.open("C:\Users\ADM\Lista Chamada\Lista Definitiva.xlsm", 0, true)
xlApp.Run "Editar_chamada"
Sheets.PrintOut(True)
Sheets.PrintOut
xlApp.Quit
set xlBook = Nothing
set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I know this code is messy and just plain wrong, but I am really noob on VBS. I am more used to Java and HTML, hence the confusion.

Comment: When I was learning VBA, I found it very useful to record a macro of what you are trying to do, then just look at the underlying code that is generated by the macro and modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: You can easly accomplish this like `roryap` mentions by recording a macro. I would however break it down into steps. `Step 1` - Copy data from Sheet1 to Sheet2. `Step 2` - Run a macro on Sheet2(no idea what kind of macro). `Step 3` - Print Sheet2. `Step 4` - Close both sheets.

Comment: Thx Bro! Nice hint, done that with my older macros and it helped me learn so much more

Comment: Ok. Been doing that. So, the original spreadsheet (the one I copy from) have variable sizes. Is there any comand I can use to select all the whole spreadsheet? Because the macro recorder always gives me the selection I made (A1:AD135 or A1:F90). Also, is there anyway to select the spreadsheet from top to last line with text? Because at a certain point I need to add margins but only to the cells with content

Comment: @N00b, why don't you do CTRL+A or select the entire sheet by clicking in the left top corner where rows/columns meet? That will select your entire sheet.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to help get you on your way:

To find the last row with data and copy over:

```
Dim LastRow As Long, DestLast As Long
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("A.xls").Range("A1:AD" & LastRow).Copy
Sheets("Lista Definitiva.xlsm").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Then to select all items and set your print area (and even a bonus of fit to 1 page wide by 1 page long:

```
DestLast = Sheets("Lista Definitiva.xlsm").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Sheets("Lista Definitiva.xlsm").PageSetup
  .Zoom = False
  .FitToPagesWide = 1
  .FitToPagesTall = 1
  .PrintArea = Range("A1:AD" & DestLast).Address
End With
```

Comment: As OP mentioned, he's noob. He don't know how to write code properly. The meaning of *Sheet* is quite often mixed (confused) with Workbook. You should be more precisly and provide more information the structure of Excel document: **Workbook.Worksheet.Range** With Respect - Maciej